# Measure of the angle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-transformation

Let  $ABCD$  an convex  quadrilateral    such  that $m(\hat{ABD})=10^{\circ}$, $m(\hat{DBC})=20^{\circ}$, $m(\hat{BAC})=100^{\circ}$ and $m(\hat{CAD})=40^{\circ}$. Find   the  measure  of  the  angle $\hat{CDB}$. I  solved  the  problem  using  just the  sine  theorem  but  I  want  to  solve   using  syntethic method. What is  necessary  to  construct?  Thank  you!

Answer (score 1):

Rotate $B$ around $A$ for $60^{\circ}$. We get new point $S$. Since $SA = SB =: r$ and $\angle ASB = 2\angle ADB$ we see that $D$ is on circle with center at $S$ and radius $r$, so we have also $DS =r$. Since $S$ is reflection of $A$ across $BC$ we have $CS = CA$ and $\angle SAC = \angle ASC = 40^{\circ}$.

Now triangle $ASD$ is isosceles ($SD=SA$) so $\angle ASD = 20^{\circ}$ and thus $BSCD$ is cyclic. This means that $$\angle BDC = 180^{\circ}-\angle BSC = 80 ^{\circ}$$

Comment: There are two positions for S and the one that makes BACS a kite is the suitable choice.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to tell me. You are offering alternative solution?

Comment: No, I am not offering an alternate solution. I just want to point out that rotating B around A for $60^0$ will give two possible images of B, one works and the other don’t.